# Почему в regex неправильно работает lookahead negative?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня имеется `regex`:

```regex
(^|])[^\[]*#
```

Он предназначен для того, чтобы находить символы `#`, которые не заключены в квадратные скобки *(скобки идут всегда парами, это проверяется отдельно)*. Если этот `regex` выдавал соответствие, то я бросал ошибку. Я использовал его для проверки примерно вот таких текстов:

```
Text text [#] text text [text#text] text text [text#].
```

Представленный выше текст валиден, в нём не будет найдено совпадений.

Мне пришлось поменять условие на противоположное. То есть мне надо сделать так, чтобы текст был валиден, если бы он соответствовал `regex`. Тогда я использовал `lookahead negative` таким образом:

```regex
(?!(^|])[^\[]*#)^.*$
```

Такой текст не выдаёт соответствие *(как и задумывалось)*:

```
Text # text [#] text text [text#text] text text [text#].
```

а вот такой почему-то проходит:

```
Text text [#] # text text [text#text] text text [text#].
```

Не понимаю, где может быть ошибка? Может быть я не знаю каких-то тонкостей в работе с `lookahead negative` в регулярных выражениях?

Comment: Уточнение: между скобками могут быть пробелы? Например, `Text [#] # text text [text text#text text] text [text#]`

Comment: @UModeL да, могут. Может быть всё что угодно, кроме неэкранированного символа `#`. Ну и подразумевается, что квадратные скобки всегда парами идут - это я предварительно проверяю.

Comment: _«Почему в regex не работает оператор отрицания?»_ - а в регулярках вообще существует оператор отрицания? :)

Comment: @yar85 ну как бы нет, но я не знаю, как эту штуку назвать) По смыслу похожа. Если с английского переводить, то будет что-то типа "Смотреть вперёд" - lookhead.

Comment: Ну так лучше было бы написать lookahead, мы тут такие термины понимаем лучше изобретенных на ходу :) По выражению - попробуй просто `/(?<!\[[^\]]*)#/`: "символ `#` если ему не предшествует <последовательность из `[` и любого количества `не-]` символов после>". Вот [тест](https://regexr.com/63btl).

Comment: В предлагаемом мной выражении нет lookahead, используется только negative lookbehind (это чуток другое: "заглядывание назад с отрицанием/инверсией"). Его по-моему достаточно, хотя конечно ничто не мешает еще и lookahead добавить после `#` (это утяжелит регулярку доп. циклом).

Comment: @yar85: почему же утяжеляет - `/#(?![^\[]*\])/g` ?

Comment: @UModeL, так это уже не добавление, а замена одного (negative lookbehind) на другое (negative lookahead) - совсем не тот кейс, о котором написано "утяжелит"... т.е., смотрим не на знакомые буковки, а на общий смысл предложения. Вот так утяжелит (хз валидно ли, иллюстрирую сам смысл): `/(?<!\[[^\]]*)#(?![^\[]*\])/`

Comment: @yar85: тяжело с юмором у Вас... ой, тяжело.

Comment: @UModeL, очень тяжело, true. Оно еще и усугубляется, тем что в пятницу вечером домашний комп сдох (БП эффектно взорвался), подкинув трат на новую комплектуху и проблемы со сгоревшими ср[ао]ками на работке (удалёнщик).

Comment: @yar85: тады паняна :) Надеюсь, всё наладится.

Comment: @yar85 во-первых соболезную вашему блоку питания (без шуток). во-вторых странно получается... На вашем сайте ваша регулярка работает, а на regex101 пишет паттерн еррор: `A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`. Не понимаю. И у вас она немного по-другому работает: мне надо наоборот, чтобы находило совпадение, если ошибки нет, или не находило бы, если ошибка есть.

Comment: @Zhenyria: ни одна из регулярок не выдаёт ошибок и работает, как требуется, если правильно скопирована.

Comment: @UModeL, нет, я не копировал, я прямо по ссылке посмотрел. Дело в том, что обратный lookahead работает только с фиксированным количеством символов, а здесь оно динамическое: `/#(?![^\[]*\])/g`. Ну и плюс всё-таки регулярка работает не совсем так, как нужно

Comment: _«обратный lookahead работает только с фиксированным количеством символов»_ == ложь и провокация. Это верно только для всяких старых и унылых реализаций рег. выражений (да, их большинство, но есть же и хорошие - например, в .NET и V8).

Comment: "Луковый" функционал вообще относительно новый, поэтому когда вoпрос о нем подразумевает какой-нибудь отсталый пыхопетонъ (например) или капризную жабку (например), это надо обязательно указывать - чтобы участники знали, с каким уровнем поддержки рег. выражений предполагается иметь дело. Есть ведь и такие реализации, которые подобного не поддерживают вовсе :)

Comment: @yar85 ну мне для джавы надо, но я глянул, она вроде бы все поддерживает. Мне об ошибке regex101 сказал ну и читал о ней где-то.

Comment: Судя по гуглу, последняя Java поддерживает lookaround'ы переменной длины (хотя и глючит когда внутри более одного квантификатора, но в данной задаче вполне можно обойтись одним). Ну а на частный сайтик regex101, кагбэ пофиг: у него же нет определяющего влияния на популярные языки и технологии использующие regexp. Проверять можно и "на месте", в целевой среде - это конечно не так удобно при отсутствии CLI-режима, но зато достовернее всяких онлайн-тестилок.

Comment: @yar85 чтож, если это уже устарело, то ок)

Answer (score 0):

Мою проблему решает следующий `regex`:

```
^((?!(^|])[^\[]*#).)*$
```

Любопытно, что я пытался использовать похожий `regex` ранее, но он не давал нужного результата:

```
^(?!(^|])[^\[]*#).*$
```

#### Что здесь происходит?

Решение я нашёл вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/14614707). Также там имеется объяснение и я его перевёл как смог *(принимаю правки)*.

Данное решение работает, потому что эти конструкции с прогнозами, которые называются `lookaround` *(обозреватель, если очень грубо)* не поглощают символы, а утверждают/подтверждают что-либо. Именно поэтому здесь: `((?!(^|])[^\[]*#).)` перед тем, как поглотить один любой символ *(точка в конце, на которую и идёт прогноз)*, идёт анализ: а не будет ли там дальше то-слово-которое-нельзя-называть?

Это всего лишь прогнозирование, поэтому достаточно всего лишь одного символа, чтобы спрогнозировать целую последовательность символов, так как этот один символ не поглощается, а служит триггером для начала анализа.

То есть наш `regex` говорит: в тексте может быть любое количество символов *(смотрим на эту часть: `.)*`)*, и на каждом символе будет запускаться прогнозирование.

По-видимому в моей предыдущей версии: `^(?!(^|])[^\[]*#).*$` прогноз шёл один раз в самом начале на всю строку. Именно поэтому такой текст проходил проверку:

```
Text text [#] # text text [text#text] text text [text#].
```

Так как вот это часть: `Text text [#] #` вовсе не соответствует этому выражению: `(^|])[^\[]*#`, если мы рассматриваем строку с самого начала.

Разумеется, производительность данного решения оставляет желать лучшего - это следует учитывать.

**P.S.: я принимаю любые правки и приглашаю профессионалов, которые меня подправят!**

Comment: Имхо, вариант `/^([^[#]*(\[[^\]]*\]))*[^\[#]*$/` для движка рег. выражений будет проще, и при прочтении человеком он воспринимается более однозначно (хоть выражение и длиннее). _//Это если для проверок, а не для извлечения совпадений._

Comment: Понятно что выражение из предыдущего комментария в данном вопросе оффтоп, т.к. здесь спрашивалось именно про lookaround... но `(?!чтолибо).`это весьма неоднозначная комбинация, из-за токена "любой символ" - по такой комбинации (по крайней мере, мне) не сразу понятно, что именно матчится выражением, и как оно себя поведет в разных ситуациях. Длинная регэксп-колбаса через исключающие наборы символов, декларативнее - если визуально распарсить ее, то без тестов можно однозначно определить что именно матчится выражением. Просто предлагаю иначе взглянуть на подход к решению, вне контекста вопроса :)

Comment: И конечно могу сейчас ошибиться, но вроде такая комбинация приводит к возврату "назад" на каждом символе входной строки (т.е., к огромному количеству итераций) - рекомендую проверить это через отладчик регулярок.

Comment: @yar85 нет, нет, у вас очень хорошая регулярка, я сейчас её анализирую, но вроде бы она работает как надо. У меня тут скорее проблема инструмента - наверное мне и не нужны были lookaround, но я к сожалению обычно в вопросах пишу конкретные моменты, а не общую проблему)

Comment: @yar85 всё, я понял, как работает ваша регулярка. Это конечно вариант куда лучше моего, что-то я не додумался, только там группа мне кажется лишняя сделана вот для этой части: `(\[[^\]]*\])` - вы сделали так просто для визуального выделения? И проверки на открывающую скобку мне кажутся излишними... Ну если учитывать то, что скобки будут проверяться на парность заранее. Я сделал вот так, теперь она чуть короче: `^([^#]*\[[^\]]*\])*[^#]*$`

Comment: Да, в моем варианте квадратная скобка в последнем токене лишняя, хорошее замечание. Но вот в первом токене, она по-моему нужна: чтобы токен матчил до скобки (учитывая что тут проверка линейная, это по сути "бесплатное" повышение надежности - оно не помешает даже при том что скобки проверяются отдельно).